# Jira and confluence change schema in docker image

Tags: docker, jira, confluence, docker-for-windows

If i run `Jira` and `Confluence` on docker, 
i see that if I want that they operate on the same DB (in my case postgres)
they need to operate on two different schemes (https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/can-confluence-share-a-database-with-jira-838424259.html).

Now i don't see on docker hub Jira (https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-software)
an environment property to change this schema.

Can you kindly tell me how to change default schema? Best option for me would be to not build custom image but use some property.

Comment: you should change the schema name at the end of `ATL_JDBC_URL`I think

Comment: previously i was starting both with `ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/rw_development`
how do i provide schema here? Default schema is `public`, `rw_development` is database name.

Comment: is not here the schema == db_name ? i am not sure about that

Comment: See this: https://imgur.com/a/5aA3Ghz I provided this env. as above and data was saved to `public` schema.